# List in Italics

Tags: lists

How can I get an entire list in italics?

Using \mdwlist package:

```
\textit{
\begin{enumerate*}
\item losses 
\item percentage 
\item main reason
\end{enumerate*}
}
```

Didn't work.

Using \enumitem didn't work:

```
\textit{
\begin{enumerate}
\item losses in numbers;
\item percentage of losses in relation to capital
\item main reason for losses
\item company's plan to eliminate losses
\end{enumerate}
}
```

tried also:

```
\begin{enumerate}[font=\italshape]
```

which didn't work.

Tried also:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\textit{
\item text
\item more text
}
\end{enumerate}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Should the list numbers (1., 2, etc) be in italics as well, or just the text? Please advise.

Comment: Both numbers and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If both the list item numerals and the list text should be rendered in italics, execute `\itshape` -- observe: it doesn't take an argument --  *before* `\begin{enumerate}`. I gather that's what you desire to achieve.
- If the list text should be rendered in italics but the list item numerals should be typeset in the upright font shape, I suggest you load the `enumitem` package, execute execute `\itshape` before `\begin{enumerate}` (as above) and start the `enumerate` environment with the option `font=\upshape`.
- If only the list item numerals should be typeset in italics, I suggest you load the `enumitem` package and start the `enumerate` environment with the option `font=\itshape`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next instruction
\itshape
\begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item more text
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\medskip
\begingroup
\itshape
\begin{enumerate}[font=\upshape]
  \item text
  \item more text
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\medskip
\begin{enumerate}[font=\itshape]
  \item text
  \item more text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```